# SQL Server 2016 access external table via polybase on azure blob storage with sql user - access denied because no login-mapping

Tags: azure, sql-server-2016, azure-blob-storage

I followed the instructions on msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935022.aspx) to create an external table. Here the code:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = <password>;  

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL BlobCredential
WITH
    IDENTITY = <identity>,
    SECRET = <secret key to access blob>
;

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE BlobContainer
WITH 
(
    TYPE = HADOOP,
    LOCATION = 'wasbs://<container>@<storageacc>.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL = BlobCredential
);

CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT FlatFile WITH
(  
    FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,   
    FORMAT_OPTIONS 
    (
        FIELD_TERMINATOR = '|', -- column delimiter 
        USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = TRUE
    )
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [stg].[TestTable]
(
[...]
)
WITH 
(
    LOCATION='/Flat/',
    DATA_SOURCE = BlobContainer,
    FILE_FORMAT = FlatFile,
    REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,
    REJECT_VALUE = 1
);
```

It's a SQL Server VM on Azure. If I connect as a local administrator to the virtual machine and connect to the SQL server instance, I can select from the table without errors. But If I connect with a sql user (sql authentication, no windows authentication) I cannot access the table. I get the following error:

> Access to the remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists.

Database scoped credentials I can't map to the sql login. Normal credentials (no database scoped credentials) I cannot use to create external data sources.

I also tried to set the key in the polybase core-site.xml ([...]/MSSQL/Binn/Polybase/Hadoop/conf/core-site.xml), but it also works only with the windows authentification (local administrator) login.

Any ideas to access external tables on azure blob storage with sql login and no windows login ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi,

if I put the user into the "sysadmin" server role, it works. Other roles doesn't work. I tested with different permissions (grant everything on server level without server role, but it didn't work).

It's bad to put an "etluser" into the sysadmin role ^^... Nobody an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a schema and Grant read access to that schema ('stg' in your example) to your sql login or role.